# Azure bicep get application id of service principal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

Bicep can be used to create a role assignment as follows:

```
resource RoleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-10-01-preview' = {
  name: guid(managementGroup().id, RoleDefinitionId, principalId)
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: roleDefinition.id
    principalId: principalId
    principalType: principalType
  }
}
```

Where the principal type is 'ServicePrincipal', it seems the application id from the Enterprise Application page of the Azure portal is required:

[image]

Does anyone know how to acquire this programatically? If it's not possible using bicep then perhaps PowerShell?

Comment: Still wondering how to do this in Bicep in favor of PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the **`Application ID`** of service principal via **PowerShell**, you can make use of below command:

```
(Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName AppName).AppId
```

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have one service principal named **`ClientApp`** and got the **Application ID** of it successfully as below:

```
(Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName ClientApp).AppId
```

**Response:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the output of resource like:

```
resource workflows_la 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows@2017-07-01' = {
  name: 'la-${env_id}-test'
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }

output logicapp_managed_identity string = workflows_la.identity.principalId
```

So you can use in role assigment resource:

```
resource roleAssignmentlogicApp 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-04-01-preview' = {
  scope: Storage
  name: guid(Storage.id, managed_identity_logic_app, roleDefinitionResourceId)
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: roleDefinitionResourceId
    principalId: managed_identity_logic_app
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in my case I need the app id of an existing service principal, rather than a managed identity of a resource

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I had to assign the Application Id of a Managed Identity (ContainerApp in my case).

I used the following:

```
resource identity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/identities@2018-11-30' existing = {
  scope: containerApp
  name: 'default'
}

output appId string = identity.properties.clientId
```